# Partial vs. Helper - Difference, but most, performance today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, partial-views, helper

I'm just trying to resolve a dilemma of Partials and Helpers in RubyOnRails 3.2.8. I'm new and yes, i tried to find, but every answer is not clear or old more than 2 years. So what's the deal?

I wonder what is best to use for this snippet. Helper or partial ?

```
<td><%= User.where("id = ?", job.created_by_id).first.email %></td>
<td><%= job.document.to_s.from(53) %></td>
<td><%= job.translation_length %></td>
<td><%= job.translation_language %></td>
<td><%= job.cost %></td>
<td><%= job.translation_type %></td>
<td><%= job.comments %></td>
<td>
  <% if job.as_soon_as_possible.to_i.equal?(0) %>
      <%= job.due_to_date %>
  <% else %>
      ASAP
  <% end %>
</td>
<td><%= job.status %></td>
```

I have used both, both work fine, but i'm not sure, if it's good hold it in partial. What about performance between rendering partial and calling helper method ? Read something about it 2 yrs old, and helpers seemed to be way faster. Is there any improvement of rendering partials?

Second, I read about using partials and helpers, but there are many opinions of developers. Am I right : Helpers are using with snippets containing more ruby code with html and Partials with html and small amount of ruby code. (According to this idea, my code above should be placed to helper)?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that helper methods are for specific proposes, they provide uniform and centralized generation of routes, and allows to avoid building some repeating html structures (in conjunction or not with model objects). And a partial is a part of the page, some semantic independent block.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your code.Now you probably listing jobs ,suppose these piece of code repeat more than one places you create partial,like adding/updating record has same fields so create form partial

Now,below code will return job due date or ASAP

```
<td>
  <% if job.as_soon_as_possible.to_i.equal?(0) %>
      <%= job.due_to_date %>
  <% else %>
      ASAP
  <% end %>
</td>
```

So creating helper which will return due date or ASAP depending upon need.

There are many more difference between partial and helper.May be if i found some useful articles i will share with you.